# How to access JSX functions from within fullcalendar's eventClick

Tags: reactjs, scope, fullcalendar

I am trying to open a JSX modal when a calendar event is clicked

I see that the problem is scope -  the fullcalendar component does not recognize my react route.
I have searched extensively without luck.
Anyone out there can help?

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  editable: false,
  locale: 'he',
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: shifts,
  eventClick: function(calEvent) {

    this.setState({ 
      calEvent      : calEvent  , 
    });

    this.deleteEventModal.open();

  }
});
```

}

Comment: This is what happens when you mix jQuery with frameworks. You likely shouldn't. FC already supports React.

Comment: Your use case is well explained in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)